# Why does curl give me wrong json for my user?

Tags: go

Something is wrong with my function

```
func (driver *DBClient) GetUsersByFirstName(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var users []models.User
    name := r.FormValue("first_name")
    // Handle response details
    var query = "select * from \"user\" where data->>'first_name'=?"
    driver.db.Raw(query, name).Scan(&users)
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    //responseMap := map[string]interface{}{"url": ""}
    respJSON, _ := json.Marshal(users)
    w.Write(respJSON)
}
```

When I use POST

```
curl -X POST \
http://localhost:8000/v1/user \
-H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
-H 'content-type: application/json' \
-d '{
"username": "tsarcayan",
"email_address": "rsarnayan@gmail.com",
"first_name": "tigran",
"last_name": "tanayan"
}'
```

Output

```
{"id":4}
```

But when I try to get first_name for user tigran

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:8000/v1/user/"tigran"
```

I got

```
{"user":{"ID":0,"CreatedAt":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z","UpdatedAt":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z","DeletedAt":null,"Orders":null},"data":null}`
```

How to fix this?

My handlefunc

```
r.HandleFunc("/v1/user", dbclient.GetUsersByFirstName).Methods("GET")
```

Comment: Try `curl -X GET http://localhost:8000/v1/user?first_name=tigran`

Comment: I got []. Take a look at my handlefunc.

Comment: You should check errors, most importantly the one from `Scan`. You should also first set headers before calling `WriteHeader`.

Comment: No, I got the same for user richard.

Comment: It looks like what you get is an empty user struct with all fields left at defaults. It means that your database query fails somewhere. Either it fails to fetch the records or it fails to scan the results into the struct. You need to check all the returned errors instead of ignoring them.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you should use url as `http://localhost:8000/v1/user?first_name=tigran` and get that parameter as `req.URL.Query()["first_name"][0]` but do not forget about user input checking